# Using SherlockMapActivity disables Eclipse auto complete feature

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, actionbarsherlock-map

I just have created a class that extends `SherlockMapActivity` from the Maps plugin of ActionBarSherlock.

Unfortunately, only in this class in the project, Eclipse auto complete won't work. It simply dislays nothing and at the bottom it sais "No completions available.".

Any ideas how I might fix this?

Goddchen

Comment: yes it does compile just fine, just auto complete is messed up :(

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?  I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: no :( would have posted it here if I had found anything :(